# How to compare duplicate element in list of list and give IF condition on another element of same list of list in python

Tags: python

friends

I have stuck in List of list problem. 
I have below type of List contains ['Score','title','ID']

```
[[0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA', 2089],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2086],
 [0.75, 'Software Tester', 2004],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2004],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1958],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1954],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2133],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2153],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2152],
 [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer', 1107],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2133],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2153],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2152],]
```

Now I want to compare ID if they similar then need to give condition which score is higher

I tried for one element code is below:

```
if cleanlist[2][2] == cleanlist[i][2]:
        if cleanlist[2][0] > cleanlist[i][0]:
            print (cleanlist[2])
        else:
            print(cleanlist[i])
```

How can I do in loops and get unique IDs with score

Desire output is below:

```
[[0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA', 2089],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2086],
 [0.75, 'Software Tester', 2004],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1958],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1954],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2133],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2153],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2152],
 [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer', 1107],]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this if you dont mind the order of output

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sort_it(list_):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for i, j, k in sorted(list_):
        res[k] = [i, j]
    return [[value[0], value[1], key] for key, value in res.items()]
```

If you want it ordered as per the IDs, then just re-sort it

```
sorted(sort_it(test_list), key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

**Working** : Input list is first sorted on basis of score, then the values are fed to a dict with ID as key and rest in list as its value, any duplicate occurence of ID's value would be replaced with new value which would be greater than previous, then re-convert it to list.

Comment: Can you please explain how its working so it will be very helpful in future?

Comment: Thank you so much I got it now

Answer (score 0):

```
a =[[0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA', 2089],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2086],
    [0.75, 'Software Tester', 2004],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2004],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1958],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1954],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2133],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2153],
    [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2152],
    [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer', 1107],
    [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2133],
    [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2153],
    [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2152]]

b = []

for i in a:
    already_in = False
    for j in b:
        if i[2] == j[2]:
            if i[0] > j[0]:
                j[0] = i[0]
                j[1] = i[1]
                j[2] = i[2]
            already_in = True
    if not already_in:
        b.append([i[0], i[1], i[2]])

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA', 2089], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2086], [0.75, 'Software Tester', 2004], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2004], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1958], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1954], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2133], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2153], [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2152], [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer', 1107], [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2133], [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2153], [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2152]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Part which I missed in my logic you put now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
cleanlist = [[0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA', 2089],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2086],
 [0.75, 'Software Tester', 2004],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2004],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1958],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 1954],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2133],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2153],
 [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer', 2152],
 [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer', 1107],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2133],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2153],
 [0.7058823529411765, 'Software Devloper', 2152]]

donelist = set()

for item in cleanlist:
    max = item[2]
    output = item
    if(item[2] not in donelist):
        for item1 in cleanlist[cleanlist.index(item):]:
            if(item[2] == item1[2] and item1[0]>max):
                output = item1
        donelist.add(item[2])
        print(output)
```

See if this can help you to get it.

Comment: Dont use `range` and indexes to iterate over a list, use `for item in list` instead.

Comment: I need range, because I am not iterating whole list twice, as you can see from the code.

Comment: You still don't need range for this. Oh and yes, you should use a `set` for `donelist` (O(1) optimised lookup instead of O(N) lookup).

Comment: Thanks for the notes, will investigate and change the answer according to suggestions.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is this what you've meant (answer is edited)?

Comment: You can use `enumerate` to get both the item and index: `for index, item in enumerate(cleanlist): ...` - this is faster and much more robust than relying on `cleanlist.index(item)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def best_scores(scores):
    best_scores = OrderedDict()
    for line in scores:
        score, _, my_id = line
        if my_id not in best_scores or score > best_scores[my_id][0]:
            best_scores[my_id] = line
    return list(best_scores.values())
```

**NB:** if you don't need the order of lines to be conserved, you could just use a standard `dict` instead of `OrderedDict`

Answer (score -1):

```
dic = {}
for item in cleanedlist:

    if item[2] in  dic:
        if dic[item[2]] < item[2]:
            dic[item[2]] = [ item[0] , item[1] ]
    else:
        dic[item[2]] = [ item[0] , item[1] ]


print(dic)
```

This will give you output in the format as below`

```
{1107: [0.9411764705882353, 'Software Engineer'],
 1954: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer'],
 1958: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer'],
 2004: [0.75, 'Software Tester'],
 2086: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer'],
 2089: [0.6428571428571429, 'Software QA'],
 2133: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer'],
 2152: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer'],
 2153: [0.7428571428571429, 'Software Developer']}
```

Using a dictionary could be a much better approach than putting everything back into the list again

Comment: Dont user `item in dict.keys()` for lookup, it's O(N), use `item in dict` which is O(1) (and highly optimised).

Comment: Well i didn't know that. Thanks for the heads up. Changing the answer